# Order dictionary in Python using value of tuple index

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

In Python 3...
Say I have a dictionary with tuples as values.  How would I sort the dictionary by a certain index of each tuple?  For example, in the dictionary below how could I sort by the service name (Netflix, Prime etc,) at index[0] of each tuple, and return the list of Keys in that order.

```
ServiceDict = {'Service01': ('Netflix', 12, 100000, 'B'), 'Service02': ('Disney', 8, 5000, 'A'), 'Service03': ('Stan', 10, 20000, 'A'), 'Service04': ('Prime', 6, 30000, 'C')}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

here the solution

```
{k: v for k, v in sorted(ServerDict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
```

duplicate you can show here more [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, Use:

```
# sorted in ascending order.
services = sorted(ServiceDict, key=lambda k: ServiceDict[k][0])
print(services)
```

This prints:

```
['Service02', 'Service01', 'Service04', 'Service03']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
ServiceDict = {k: v for k, v in sorted(ServiceDict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][0])}

print(list(ServiceDict.keys()))
```

Output will be-

```
['Service02', 'Service01', 'Service04', 'Service03']
```